# ef and linq extension method

Tags: linq, entity-framework, extension-methods

I have this sql that i want to have written in linq extension method returning an entity from my edm:

```
SELECT p.[Id],p.[Firstname],p.[Lastname],prt.[AddressId],prt.[Street],prt.[City] 
FROM [Person] p 
CROSS APPLY ( 
    SELECT TOP(1) pa.[AddressId],a.[ValidFrom],a.[Street],a.[City]
    FROM [Person_Addresses] pa 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Addresses] AS a
    ON a.[Id] = pa.[AddressId]
    WHERE p.[Id] = pa.[PersonId] 
    ORDER BY a.[ValidFrom] DESC ) prt
```

Also could this be re-written in linq extension method using 3 joins?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set the Person_Addresses table up as a pure relation table (i.e., with no data besides the foreign keys) this should do the trick:

```
    var persons = model.People
      .Select(p => new { p = p, a = p.Addresses.OrderByDescending(a=>a.ValidFrom).First() })
      .Select(p => new { p.p.Id, p.p.Firstname, p.p.LastName, AddressId = p.a.Id, p.a.Street, p.a.City });
```

The first Select() orders the addresses and picks the latest one, and the second one returns an anonymous type with the properties specified in your query.

If you have more data in your relation table you're gonna have to use joins but this way you're free from them. In my opinion, this is more easy to read.

NOTE: You might get an exception if any entry in Persons have no addresses connected to them, although I haven't tried it out.

Comment: Thanks for response, however i'm looking for another solution in which the query returns not a projection.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of query you are looking for; do you mean that you simply want the Person entities and (for each one) their latest address?